# Spring retroactive topic jms listener to fetch only latest message after restart

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

**Requirements:**
In one project I need to fetch messages from topic.
When my app will be restarted or started after the publisher already sent some messages the app should re-fetch but only the last message put on topic.

**What I did:**
I have created a spring jms listener which is a topic subscriber using annotation. It is a durable retroactive listener with a random client id so that it will fetch messages sent before subscription start and after every restart producer will treat it as a new subscriber and will send messages already consumed before the restart.

**Problem:**
After restart all previously sent messages are being fetched and the requirement is that only the last message sent will be fetched.

ActiveMQ is my message broker and I cannot administer it.

I will greatly appreciate any hint how to do that better? :)

Cheers

Comment: hello, you cannot use a static client id ?

Comment: No, if I will do that after every app restart message broker will know that I have already fetched messages so I won't re-fetch them. :( It has to be durable so it can be retroactive and it has to have a different client id every time it starts to be able to fetch what it already did fetch during previous run.

Comment: why : fetch what it already did fetch during previous run ??

Comment: On topic there is some periodically refreshed data used by the application when it is running and still there is a requirement that the application itself shouldn't persist anything.